# Prepend div on top of the nearest div

Tags: jquery

Is there anyway to prepend the messages error before the webform component using jquery? I tried the to use the sibling but the messages error got duplicated. Currently the error notice display at the bottom of the field I want to place it on top of the field

[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z56XJ.jpg)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miX0i.jpg)

Comment: Try this http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

Answer (score 0):

You can try the prepend function like Sagar had commented. Here is the simple sample.

```js
$("#submit").click(function() {

  $('.web-form-component--first-name').prepend('<div class="messages error">Error First name</div>');

  $('.web-form-component--last-name').prepend('<div class="messages error">Error Last name</div>');

  return false;

});
```

```css
.error {
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
}

.messages {
  padding: 6px;
  margin:4px;
}
input{
  width:100%;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form">
  <div class="web-form-component--first-name">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First name">
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="web-form-component--last-name">
    <input type="text" name="lasttname" placeholder="Last name">
  </div>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```